# At what altitude does oxygen have no effect on the shape of a rocket?

Tags: pressure, aerodynamics, rocket-science

At what altitude does oxygen/air have no effect on the shape of a rocket?

Meaning at what altitude is there no air for nose cones to have any effect on the rocket's performance?

Reason I'm asking is because I contacted a space company (http://www.zero2infinity.space/bloostar/) asking them why they used a nose cone and this is what they said:

`Bloostar has a nose cone for two main reasons: the first one is that even though Bloostar is "flown" until past 99% of the atmosphere, it still has to pass the atmosphere. It is easier for the balloon to fly with a nose-cone-Bloostar than one without it. The second reason is that the 1% of atmosphere that is still left has a bit of air.`

Comment: The Von Karman line is considered to be 100km which is the edge of space. I doubt the ballon can get anywhere near the high, so there will be friction as the rocket climbs.

Comment: Air is only 1/5 oxygen.

Comment: I don't understand that quote.  He says "_even though Bloostar is "flown" until past 99% of the atmosphere, it still has to pass the atmosphere_" then he says "_The second reason is that the 1% of atmosphere that is still left has a bit of air._" Those seem like equivalent statements, so that's only one reason.  Not _overly_ relevant, I just don't understand the quote (unless he's just being very redundant).

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v1): Replace the word _oxygen_ with the word _air._

Answer (score 1):

As zeta-band said in his comment, 100 km altitude is often used as the height where the atmosphere becomes thin enough not to be a major factor in missile flight. I know that many people use this in studies on missiles. So it is the accepted altitude by some communities.